# How to find directories with particular name

Tags: android

Any app can create folder in external storage. 
This folder can be placed at SD card or phone inner memory.
If i use this code, i can to get list of all my external storages.

```
File file2[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
```

it return:
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.snailp4el.android.tatoeba/files
/storage/8639-0FFD/Android/data/com.snailp4el.android.tatoeba/files
but if i try to get list of it path:

```
File f = new File("/storage/8639-0FFD/Android/data/com.snailp4el.android.tatoeba/files");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

I get nothing.
in this case:

```
File f = new File("/storage/");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

i get:

```
/storage/8639-0FFD
/storage/emulated
/storage/self
```

That is OK. i finally get all storages in my phone.
Question is:
How to scan subfolders to find particular folders by name?
And is my approach right. I mean to scan "/storage"?
And if Yes will it work at all version?
and finally what is "/storage/self"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.
May by it is not the best solution but it works fine for me.

```
public ArrayList getExternalFolderPath(String folderName){

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

//get all storages in phone
File externalStorages[] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

for (File es: externalStorages){
    String exF = es.toString();

    //cut out what don't need
    exF = exF.split("/Android/data")[0];

    File file = new File(exF);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File f: files){
        Log.i(TAG, "getAnkiExternalFolder()" + f.toString());
        //add in array the path
        if(f.toString().contains(folderName)){
            arrayList.add(f.toString());
        }
    }
}
return arrayList;
}
```

You can get two directories(from both storage). The directory you need the last changed one.

```
file.lastModified()
```